# Enable a button dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, controller

I have an empty array, upon page load, since there are no values stored in this array, I disabled the button using `ng-disabled="array1.length==0"`. In the page that opens up I have four drop downs present. What I am trying to achieve is the button should be enabled when I select even one option of the four drop downs.

But just by adding the `ng-disabled` to the button does not calculated the length of the array dynamically.

I have declared 
`array1=
[{name1:''},
{name2:''},
{name:''}]`. I just figured out that the length will never be 0. I want the button to be disable when the values are '' and enabled once user selects a value.

The fields present in the page are configurable, So all the four fields that I show by default in the page, come under one model. `ng-model="model[value.Name]"` This will give me the four drop downs (I do a ng-repeat).So I cannot add a hard coded value to the `ng-disabled` as they are dynamic values.

Any suggestions on how do I get this done?

Comment: ng-disabled="array1.length==0" Used it, Because always Array length 0.

Comment: Does not work. When I put that, the button is not disabled.

Comment: Can you add a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: did you intialize array1 =[] or array1 =''?

Comment: Edited the question to give more clear picture

Comment: @VijayPatel I have declared array1=[name1:'',name2:'',name:'']. I just figured out that the length will never be 0. I want the button to be disable when the values are '' and enabled once user selects a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with that ng-disabled='ddl1 || ddl2 || dd3 || dd4' !!!

Comment: This can't work. It will be disabled every time if only one dropdown is selected and will be enabled only initially which was not requested in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `ng-disabled="!value1 && !value2 && !value3 && !value4`
Where value1, value2, value3, value4 represents ng-model's of the mentioned dropdowns. In case that some of those dropdown values has a selected value button should be enabled.

Comment: This is not valid array: 
array1=
[name1:'',
name2:'',
name:'']

Please, explain better how it looks.

Comment: I did not understand as to why this array is not valid? I am able to view the values without any error! Correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: This is not valid  = array1= [name1:'', name2:'', name:''], this is valid: array1= [{name1:''}, {name2:''}, {name:''}]; But I see that you edited your post after my comment :)

Comment: I tried your solution and that works.. But then there are again if's and but's to look into.. But to get my problem solved for the moment this works :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

find my answer. i hope your array format is to be changed as array on json as shown in controller.

```
$scope.myarray = [{name:''},{name:'name2'},{name:'name3'}];
```

html

```
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
 <button ng-disabled="!selectedName.name && !selectedName2.name" '>button</button>

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.name for x in myarray"></select>
   <select ng-model="selectedName2" ng-options="x.name for x in myarray"></select>
</body>
```

controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
$scope.myarray = [{name:''},{name:'name2'},{name:'name3'}];            
    }]);
```

please find the plunker
[Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fFCHHIWOdSJ2dcJvwEv?p=preview)

Comment: I cannot change the array to have same `name`. If I do so then I will not be able to achieve user configuration.

Comment: then how are to looping with ng-repeat. paste ur html code and controller code in your question to get clarity

Comment: I still have to try the way you suggested.. Will update once done :)